# WiX - reinstallation failed when doesn't exists folder any more

Tags: wix

I've a problem with reinstallation, where doesn't exists a subfolder, what was in version before. In version 1 there in some wxs file exists:

```
<Component Id="cmp7EB6415256FC5DA344472986974956E4" Directory="dir74C41F8B6B03DD308C9CCD0008B2F7E5" Guid="{9BD5E948-E8EA-4C5E-B5F4-7002B28765D9}" KeyPath="yes" MultiInstance="yes">
   <CreateFolder />
</Component>
```

In version 2 it doesn't exists. During reinstallation there is no phase copy files and original files remaininig, but there is no error at the end. When I remove the component new files are copied.

The wxs file is created by heat. I have a quite huge number of folders and subfolders, and the project is dynamic. It means that everybody can add or remove a folder and I cannot check if somebody deleted any of them.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Installer only creates Directories that are required to install Files or that are explicitly called out by a CreateFolder element. You'll need to add a CreateFolder somewhere to get the empty Directories to remain.